# Ruby on Rails: how do I get the top 5 of something?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a column, money, 
   and I want the top 5 most expensive activeRecord items.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find(:all, order => "money desc" :limit => 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails 3 (ARel) syntax:

```
Item.order('items.money DESC').limit(5)
```